# Tags marked "do not use"?

Tags: discussion, tags

Today, after browsing for some JBoss related Java questions to answer, I noticed this:

[image: jboss tag]

I don't understand why this has been done.

Previously, I used the tag as a catch all to view 'questions I have a good chance of answering'. After all, anyone with experience of using JBoss enough to be answering questions, probably has experience of / or that will apply to more than one specific version.

I also used the tag a a quick link to view a list of enterprise related Java questions with a common theme (EJB's, persistence, JMS, RMI etc.). After all, if you're using JBoss, it'll be to gain the use of its designed functions.

From my experience, many genuinely version specific JBoss questions, relate more towards the setup and config (possibly more appropriate on https://serverfault.com/?) of the application server, instead of being a programming problem.

We don't push Java language questions to use a version specific tag. I also checked the Tomcat tag, as it relates to Java questions in much the same way (a very common Java web container), yet the tag there isn't marked "do not use".

What's the correct approach? Should questions use version-agnostic tags at all? Is the case for JBoss different to Tomcat because of question volumes or some other factor?

Comment: Many of the "great tag cleanup" have had their wikis changed to this while cleanup continues. Don't know if this is one though

Comment: Maybe - I know its why I lost my beloved "japanese" tag. :(

Comment: We need tag trees. (Was that already suggested?)

Comment: I find too that we have too precise tags, they shouldn't precise the version. This makes the tagging hard to guess, inconsistent, and useless for filters and searches.

Comment: @minitech: Searching for tags brings up all of the relevant ones, as you can see in the illustration above.  What someone really wants is a burnination, which is ridiculous for this tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't agree with the words "Do Not Use" on this tag, but maybe the JBoss community could provide some further explanation.  We don't force people to use .NET-3.5 instead of .NET, or C#-4.0 instead of C#, and I don't see why this should be any different.