# Could we change the tag excerpt/wiki and clean up the [survey] tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, clean-up

Currently the [survey](/questions/tagged/survey) excerpt says

> DO NOT USE this tag; questions about the annual Stack Overflow user surveys should be asked on Meta Stack Overflow, not here.

But this tag could be used on questions about surveys in general not only about the annual Stack Overflow surveys like

- [Let's Start An Annual Meta Survey!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/306253/289691)
- [Give each site a parallel site for polling, recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57383/289691)
- [Are research survey questions expected to be handled with close votes?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/278250/289691)

Considering that [survey](/questions/tagged/survey) has a lot of questions about the Stack Overflow Annual Survey, once this is "approved", the next step should be that a Meta SE Moderator [rename the tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/87437/289691) to something like `stackoverflow-annual-survey`, which has less than 35 characters, then create the [survey](/questions/tagged/survey) again.

Notes:

- Related tags: [polling](/questions/tagged/polling), [list-questions](/questions/tagged/list-questions)
- My "first" thought was to use the same title as the revision 2 of [Tags marked "do not use"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135677/289691) (Tags marked "do not use"?) but that question is about Stack Overflow and more specifically JBoss related questions, so I proposed an edit to that question to make the title more specific and to add some tags.

According to [answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/137837/289691) to [Why can I tag a question with a tag marked 'DO NOT USE'?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/137836/289691) :

> The "DO NOT USE" is purely a convention from the community to mark
>   tags that are supposed to be removed. Those are not supposed to exist
>   for long, only until the tag is eliminated and replaced by better
>   tags. There never was a feature that would prevent those tags from
>   being used.
>
> There is a feature to blacklist tags, but that is developer-only and
>   used very rarely. It is also generally not used on existing tags, but
>   the tag is removed completely and then blacklisted, to avoid any
>   confusion.

Related

- [Please make [polling] a synonymous of [list-questions]?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/320644/289691)

Comment: Very related: [Conduct a \[survey\] about tags on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/341846/335251)/ (Per Spevacus' answer there, I've now renamed the [survey] tag to [stack-overflow-developer-survey]; I also added [survey] and a few alternatives as synonyms of the tag.) Also, note that the tag wiki no longer reads as quoted in this question; it currently says: "DO NOT USE this tag unless your question is about the Developer Survey's integration with sites other than Stack Overflow." Certain questions about the survey are still allowed on MSE, according to the community.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to your proposed changes I suggest to create a tag warning ([example 1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347924/nullpointers-add-links-to-what-it-is-and-the-tag-similar-to-regex), [example 2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290740/provide-asking-instructions-for-regex-just-like-for-sql)) for the survey tags. This would probably be a bit more visible than just the excerpt and may help to reduce the amount of developer survey questions even further.

Suggested wording:

> - **Questions about the Stack Overflow developer survey belong on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com)**
> - If you want to ask whether polling questions (e.g. "What is your favorite ...?") are allowed on a specific site in the Stack Exchange network, ask on the per-site Meta.
> - If you have a question about surveys on a specific site in the Stack Exchange network, ask on the per-site Meta.
> - If you want to propose a network-wide survey, explain why you think such a survey is necessary and what questions you would like to have included. Also read [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377152/stack-overflow-academic-research-partnership-program).
> - Although discussions are on-topic on Meta Stack Exchange, they must be problem-oriented (e.g. "Should we do this?" and not "What is your favorite feature").